# Not able to connect android application to PHP mysql database using JSON in the debugging device[application got connected in avd]

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to learn how to use JSON to connect my android app to PHP mysql database.So i have imported the project from [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) website.The database is present in the localhost.The record got inserted in the database when i ran the code in the avd using the following server address:

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/
```

But during the presentation in my college I will have to show it in a Tab/phone. I have tried the following things so that the app starts working:

1) Started 2G/3G in my mobile connected the laptop with my mobile through hotspot.
2) Connected my mobile with my laptop using USB cable(this was suggested by one of the seniors in the college)
3) Changed the server address to the ip address of the network created by the mobile.

The app crashes while we try to add a record or view a record.

Also I have both IIS and WAMP running in my laptop as I have manually configured WAMP to 8080 port.

Please let me know how to run this app in a device while the database is in the localhost. Does having IIS and WAMP on a single laptop create such problems?

**EDIT**

**LOGCAT**

```
03-02 18:49:16.796: W/ApplicationPackageManager(20675): getCSCPackageItemText()
03-02 18:49:34.621: D/ProgressBar(20675): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
03-02 18:49:34.621: D/ProgressBar(20675): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
03-02 18:49:34.621: D/ProgressBar(20675): updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
03-02 18:49:34.621: D/ProgressBar(20675): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
03-02 18:50:37.896: I/System.out(20675): AsyncTask #1 calls detatch()
03-02 18:50:37.896: W/System.err(20675): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.43.77:8080 refused
03-02 18:50:37.901: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:212)
03-02 18:50:37.901: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)
03-02 18:50:37.901: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
03-02 18:50:37.901: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1179)
03-02 18:50:37.901: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:644)
03-02 18:50:37.901: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-02 18:50:37.901: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-02 18:50:37.901: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-02 18:50:37.906: W/System.err(20675):    at com.example.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:51)
03-02 18:50:37.906: W/System.err(20675):    at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:95)
03-02 18:50:37.906: W/System.err(20675):    at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:1)
03-02 18:50:37.906: W/System.err(20675):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-02 18:50:37.906: W/System.err(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-02 18:50:37.911: W/System.err(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-02 18:50:37.911: W/System.err(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-02 18:50:37.911: W/System.err(20675):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-02 18:50:37.911: W/System.err(20675): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.77 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
03-02 18:50:37.916: W/System.err(20675):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
03-02 18:50:37.916: W/System.err(20675):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-02 18:50:37.916: W/System.err(20675):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-02 18:50:37.916: W/System.err(20675):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
03-02 18:50:37.916: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-02 18:50:37.921: W/System.err(20675):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
03-02 18:50:37.921: W/System.err(20675):    ... 15 more
03-02 18:50:37.921: W/System.err(20675): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
03-02 18:50:37.926: W/System.err(20675):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-02 18:50:37.926: W/System.err(20675):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
03-02 18:50:37.926: W/System.err(20675):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-02 18:50:37.931: W/System.err(20675):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-02 18:50:37.931: W/System.err(20675):    ... 20 more
03-02 18:50:37.931: E/Buffer Error(20675): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
03-02 18:50:37.931: E/JSON Parser(20675): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-02 18:50:37.936: W/dalvikvm(20675): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41814c08)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 20675
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:99)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:1)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-02 18:50:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    ... 3 more
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42a91230 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-655,346} that was originally added here
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:456)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:76)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:56)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-02 18:50:38.301: E/WindowManager(20675):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your `logcat` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Please see the logcat it has been added in the Edit section of my question

Comment: make sure that your tab/smartphone and your laptop are connected to the same network , then put the IP of your laptop as the address of server

Comment: @Ziprox09 I tried that method. Still not able to connect to db

Comment: I suggest you to check your internet connection. also make sure make sure that your tab/smartphone and your laptop are connected to the same network

Comment: I tried it again. My laptop and my mobile are connected to the same wifi. But still it is not getting connected to db